# Communication between C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, grpc

I want to use GRPC in C# and Java.

C# should act as a server and Java as a client.

I am a windows user and do not know, how to generate a proto file for C# and Java.

On the website, I found only tutorials for specific language but not for different languages.

Comment: Consider something like ZeroMQ. It's much easier than raw socket programming.

Comment: What is the difference between ZeroMQ and GRPC?

Comment: What about RabbitMQ? I feel there have more attention then ZeroMQ

Answer (score 0):

Using gRPC in both C# and Java should be just as easy as using them individually. All you need to do is use the same `.proto` file to generate code for each. The `.proto` defines the methods and messages that both C# and Java would be compatible with.

If you look at each set of examples, they each use the same `.proto` (i.e., `helloworld.proto` or `route_guide.proto`). The examples are compatible between languages (i.e., C# helloworld server can communicate with Java helloworld client).

Specifying gRPC services in proto files is pretty straight-forward; I'd assume just looking at the examples would make that clear enough. For more information about defining proto messages, you may take a look at the [protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to allow these applications to communicate would be to create client server applications using sockets... C#, acting as a server should listen for a client connection on a specified port while, the Java application, acting as a client, should send a connection request on the same port the c# application Is listening on... Beings that these applications are connected via a network language is no longer relevant. You can simply pass data between the applications freely although each application might handle the data differently. Hope this helps.

Comment: That what GRPC should do.